# Is "Your voice was not audible for a sec" wrong in a corporate setting?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-choice

Today I was speaking to someone from HR. Due to some disturbance over the line, I could not hear her voice for a second or so. So I told her "Your voice was not audible for a sec" and asked her to repeat the last question.

Is "Your voice was not audible for a sec" wrong English, especially in a corporate setting? Would "You are not audible, could you repeat your last question" be better?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think she didn't understand.  For example did she repeat the question in her normal voice?

Answer (score 1):

I think "You weren't audible", or "Your voice wasn't audible" are both correct. We use "I can hear you" and "I can hear your voice" to mean similar things.

However, "Not audible" suggests "too quiet". So this wouldn't be the phrasing I would use.

It is often better, in fairly formal settings to speak what happened to yourself describe events using "I" or "There is" sentences, rather than "You" sentences.  I would say:

> Sorry I didn't catch the last thing you said. Could you repeat it?

> Sorry, there was some disturbance (or interference) on the line, could you repeat that last thing you said?

However "You weren't audible" is fine. It communicates the problem quite well, and is polite and formal.

Answer (score 0):

I think anything that makes noise can be or not be ***audible***. Therefore, I don't see why both your sentences wouldn't be correct, strictly speaking. However, with any language one must be mindful of what is more commonly used.

At least in written texts, [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=voice%20is%20not%20audible%2Cyou%20are%20not%20audible%2C%20cannot%20hear%20you%2Ccould%20not%20hear%20you&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvoice%20is%20not%20audible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20are%20not%20audible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20hear%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20hear%20you%3B%2Cc0) shows that ***you are not audible*** is slightly more frequent than ***your voice is not audible***, but are in fact both quite rare. It also shows that ***I cannot hear you*** is the phrase people actually use the most (note that it is more common than ***I could not hear you***). I also checked ***I lost you for a second***, but the result was insignificant.

I think that an expression like ***I cannot hear you***, although it is so very common, can perfectly be used in a formal context:

> I am (really) sorry, I cannot hear you. Do you mind repeating your last question?

Note: ***for a sec*** is not really acceptable in formal speech. If you want to use the expression you can also consider putting it in this way:

> I am (really) sorry, Sir, I could not hear you for a second. Do you mind repeating
> your last question?

Comment: Is "you are not audible" perhaps associated with particular dialects of English? Having attended a few online conferences/events with speakers from India, I've noticed that it seems to be a commoner phrase in Indian English than I'm used to in British English.

Comment: Very possible. I have no such experience, however, so I cannot tell. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: OP is addressing a woman, so perhaps change "Sir"  (I don't think its appropriate to use "sir" to a colleague in general, but opinions differ)